# Is it possible to show only sender name when sending email from Python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to send email using Python and `smptlib`. Is it possible to format message body so that it shows the sender's name only instead of name and email?

Currently I am composing the email message like this

```
from email.utils import formataddr
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header('John Smith', 'utf-8')), 'john.smith@outlook.com'))
msg['To'] = "abc@outlook.com"
msg['Subject'] = 'title'
msg.set_content('content message')
```

In the inbox it will show the name only (`John Smith`) as expected, but when I open the message it shows name and the email in pointy brackets: `John Smith <john.smith@outlook.com>`

Is it possible to show only John Smith name without the email in the email message? I want to still keep the email somehow so that the name is correctly associated with that email when I hover over it in Outlook. If I send name only like this `msg['From'] = 'John Smith'` then the name will be greyed out and won't have any details for that person from the address book in Outlook.

Comment: The _body_ doesn't contain this information. If you mean in the headers, then no, you can't hide the recipient's address (though `Bcc:` would hide the recipient information entirely).

Comment: Many things which are possible with SMTP are not possible with Outlook. If you donwt specifically require an Outlook solution, probably remove it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, RFC5322 does not allow you to insert a `From:` header which does not contain an email address.

Some mail servers will quietly ignore the problem if you submit a malformed message. For example, if you omit

```
msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header('John Smith', 'utf-8')), 'john.smith@outlook.com'))`
```

from your code (or insert the header with just a name, like you suggest), the message you send might be rejected, or might be delivered without a `From:` header, or might be delivered with a `From:` header synthesized more or less out of the blue.

As a general precaution, many spam filters take hard exception with malformed messages like this, and so you might end up in a situation where the end result is less to your liking than the original problem.

Of course, hiding the email address will also prevent it from being linked to the sender's identity; i.e. there is no way the recipient would be able to connect the message to an address book entry or previous correspondence.

This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway. If you don't want to divulge your personal email address, register a new one with Gmail, Proton, Mailinator, or hundreds of others.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already been told, you should always send syntactically correct messages, so the `From:`  header, if present should contain a syntactically correct address. That means at least a mail address and optionaly a full name, but the address is not required to exist. If you format you header as:

```
From: "John Smith" dummy@dummy.com
```

it will be a perfectly valid header.

Simply that could raise a number of red flags on any anti-malware system and the mail is in risk of ending in a trash bin...

Comment: Actually it needs to have angle brackets around `<dummy@dummy.com>`. If you don't own the `dummy.com` domain name, your actions could have undesired consequences for an unrelated third party (but you could use `<dummy@dummy.invalid>` to prevent such accidents).

Answer (score 0):

That is just how Outlook works - it always parses the sender info into name and address (these are stored in separate MAPI properties), but in the UI it is free to show the combination of the two or just the name.

Comment: The OP is asking about SMTP, so what exactly that gets translated into in Outlook's stunted little mind is a secondary concern.

Comment: The OP wanted particular behavior in Outlook, it is just he thought it can be achieved in his code that sends through SMTP. That behavior is not at all SMTP specific. This is an Outlook end-user question.

Comment: But how come that when message is sent directly from my account it will show up without the email adress in brackets (only the name), but when sent using the script via smtp then it will show up like that?

Comment: If your mailbox is hosted by Exchange, your address is of type `EX` (a long ugly looking string), not `SMTP`.  Take a look at the message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).